# Loopback - Find Request Error - filter and included model

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs

Hi I am having some trouble with a Find request using loopback.

I'm using a "loopback-connector-rest" connector (& my API is using MongoDB).

I have 2 classes

- ClassA hasAndBelongsToMany ClassB
- ClassB properties : {author: {uid: 'string', ...}, ...}

When I use the request below, I get the error:

> *MongoError*
>   *statusCode 500*
>   *Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $nin needs an array*

```
ClassA.find({
    'filter': {
        'include': {
            'relation': 'classB',
            'scope': {
                'where': {
                    'author.uid': {
                        'nin': ['test1', 'test2']
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, cb);
```

From the mongo log, I found the error occurs at:

```
$query: { author.uid: { $nin: { [0]: "test1", [1]: "test2" } }
```

I do not understand why an error occurs here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have edited your code as per [documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter).

```
ClassA.find({
    include: {
        relation: 'classB',
        scope: {
            where: {
                'author.uid': {
                    nin: [
                        'test1',
                        'test2'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, cb);
```